# Copy pregenerated files to output folder when project is reference by other project

Tags: c#, msbuild

Let's say, I've got two projects. `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`. `A.csproj` references `B.csproj` which contains files that needs to be pregenerated during the compilation and included in the output. I would like to treat them as post compilation artifacts that are required to be present in the final binary directory.

in `b.csproj` I defined custom after compile target:

```
    <Target Name="GenerateEmails" AfterTargets="AfterCompile">
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\ForgetPassword"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\PasswordChanged"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Removed"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Welcome"/>
        <Exec Command="mjml $(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\ForgetPassword\Content.mjml -o $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\ForgetPassword\Content.html"/>
        <Exec Command="mjml $(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\Removed\Content.mjml -o $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Removed\Content.html"/>
        <Exec Command="mjml $(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\Welcome\Content.mjml -o $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Welcome\Content.html"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\PasswordChanged\Subject.txt" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\PasswordChanged\"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\ForgetPassword\Subject.txt" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\ForgetPassword\"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\Removed\Subject.txt" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Removed\"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\Welcome\Subject.txt" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Emails\Welcome\"/>
    </Target>
```

and it works fine if I build `B.csproj` where this target is defined however when I build it from `A.csproj` required folder is missing in `A\bin\debug\netcore\6.0` folder.

How to make this folder to be considered as a regular `.dll` file that must be present especially when `B` project is referenced project

Comment: 1. Add post-build events in A, copy files from B. 2 Set output path of A and B to same folder.

Comment: I would like to make it work without having to modify A.csproj, this files should be considered as a regular build artifacts (ie. B.dll) and copied to referencing directory

Comment: A project reference in A.csproj to B.csproj doesn't copy everything in the output folder of B.csproj. The target of B.csproj will be copied (e.g. B.dll) and certain related files where the name matches the target (e.g. B.pdb, B.dll.config).